# Docker version 20.10.23: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon

Tags: docker, docker-compose

After updating my mac to version 12.6.3, i was forced to uninstall and install my docker desktop again, the current version that i have is "Docker version 20.10.23, build 7155243". i can run the command "docker --version", but when i try to run commands like *docker-compose up* or *docker ps* i get this error:
**Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?**

Any idea what i can do about this? again i installed docker desktop and it is running, but none of the commands for enabling docker is not working for me.

Comment: did you start docker-desktop? The client will always tell you the version but other commands need the deamon to be running and this is done by starting the docker-desktop service.

Comment: @TheFool i did follow the instruction on docker document "Install Docker Desktop on Mac" to install, is there another step i need to take?

Comment: You need to start docker desktop. The same way you would start any other app. i.e. search in your start menu for it and double click it.

Comment: @TheFool this is exactly what i did, as i mentioned when i click on docker icon i can see in the menu it's green and shows docker desktop is running.